# How do I highlight a bunch of files with Mousekeys in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7

When I try to highlight a couple of files it doesn't work when I only use Mousekeys.  When I use the right-click button and try to highlight with the arrow keys of the mumberpad nothing happens...how do I highlight files in Explorer using only Mousekeys?

Win 7 Pro.

Comment: Are you meaning to drag them or just highlight text?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to highlight or select by dragging: Press <kbd>0</kbd>, then move the cursor selecting the desired area and press <kbd>.</kbd> to stop.

If you are trying to select multiple files: Use <kbd>5</kbd> to click on a file, then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>5</kbd> to select additional files. Or to select all files in order: click the first file, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the last file to select all files in between and inclusive of the clicked files (same as with using the normal mouse).

[Windows documentation on using Mouse Keys](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer)